# How to write a code where user can give the elements of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I wanted to write a code where user will give input the element of the array and then the elements will be print as an array. Here is my code but the code do not give the array as output.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int arr[100] , size , i , num ; //Here we are defining the maximum size of array is 100. So user can choose the size of array by him/her but cannot choose more than 100

cout << "Enter the size of array (Maximum array size you can take is 100) : ";
cin >> size;

if (size > 100)
{
    cout << "You cannot take the size more than 100" << endl;
}else{

    cout << "Inter the elements using space : ";
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i];
        }

    cout << "Enter data you want to insert : ";
    cin >> num;
        for (int i = size - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];
        }
    arr[0] = num;
    size++;
    }

    cout << arr[i] << endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. Do you want to have a possibility of creating arrays bigger than 100 elements or do you want to know how to output the constants of the array?

Comment: Well, you're only printing `arr[i]`, and `i` is uninitialized... Perhaps you need another loop?

Comment: « give the array as output » To display the entire array `for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) { std::cout << arr[i] << '\n'; }`

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I see two basic problems.

First, you define variable i at the top of your code. That's fine, although there are arguments for variable names being longer than a single character. Think about searching for uses of that variable -- you're going to get it in all sorts of places that have nothing to do with the variable. while has an i. if has an i. Be that as it may.

But here's a real problem. You have some for loops like this:

```
for (int i = 0; ....)
```

There's nothing wrong with that, not exactly. It works. HOWEVER, it's considered bad form to reuse a variable inside an inner block that matches a variable from an outer block. It's legal, but it's a common source of bugs. I recommend you don't do it.

Then, at the bottom, you do this:

```
cout << arr[i] << endl;
```

At this point, we're back to the original variable i that you declare at the top. But you never actually initialize it, so it's some random value. And you're not doing any sort of loop.

I suspect if you wrap this inside another of your for-loops, you'd get the results you want.

And get rid of declaring i at the top.